# Which bcrypt cost to use for 2018?

Tags: go, encryption, hash, bcrypt

## Update

Actually it seems the benchmark was incorrectly setup I have followed the [resource shared](https://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/30/how-to-write-benchmarks-in-go) by user @Luke Joshua Park and now it works.

```
package main

import "testing"

func benchmarkBcrypt(i int, b *testing.B){
    for n:= 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        HashPassword("my pass", i)
        }

}

func BenchmarkBcrypt9(b *testing.B){
    benchmarkBcrypt(9, b)
}

func BenchmarkBcrypt10(b *testing.B){
    benchmarkBcrypt(10, b)
}

func BenchmarkBcrypt11(b *testing.B){
    benchmarkBcrypt(11, b)
}

func BenchmarkBcrypt12(b *testing.B){
    benchmarkBcrypt(12, b)
}

func BenchmarkBcrypt13(b *testing.B){
    benchmarkBcrypt(13, b)
}

func BenchmarkBcrypt14(b *testing.B){
    benchmarkBcrypt(14, b)
}
```

Output:

```
BenchmarkBcrypt9-4            30      39543095 ns/op
BenchmarkBcrypt10-4           20      79184657 ns/op
BenchmarkBcrypt11-4           10     158688315 ns/op
BenchmarkBcrypt12-4            5     316070133 ns/op
BenchmarkBcrypt13-4            2     631838101 ns/op
BenchmarkBcrypt14-4            1    1275047344 ns/op
PASS
ok      go-playground   10.670s
```

---

## Old incorrect benchmark

I have a small set on benchmark test in golang and am curios of to what is a recommended bcrypt cost to use as of May 2018.

This is my benchrmark file:

```
package main

import "testing"

func BenchmarkBcrypt10(b *testing.B){
    HashPassword("my pass", 10)
}

func BenchmarkBcrypt12(b *testing.B){
    HashPassword("my pass", 12)
}

func BenchmarkBcrypt13(b *testing.B){
    HashPassword("my pass", 13)
}


func BenchmarkBcrypt14(b *testing.B){
    HashPassword("my pass", 14)
}

func BenchmarkBcrypt15(b *testing.B){
    HashPassword("my pass", 15)
}
```

and this is `HashPassword()` func inside `main.go`:

```
import (
    "golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt"
)

func HashPassword(password string, cost int) (string, error) {
    bytes, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(password), cost)
    return string(bytes), err
}
```

The current output is:

```
go test -bench=.
BenchmarkBcrypt10-4     2000000000           0.04 ns/op
BenchmarkBcrypt12-4     2000000000           0.16 ns/op
BenchmarkBcrypt13-4     2000000000           0.32 ns/op
BenchmarkBcrypt14-4            1    1281338532 ns/op
BenchmarkBcrypt15-4            1    2558998327 ns/op
PASS
```

It seems that for a bcrypt with cost of 13 the time it takes is 0.32 nanoseconds, and for cost 14 the time is 1281338532ns or ~1.2 seconds
Which I believe is too much. What do is the best bcrypt cost to use for the current year 2018.

Comment: 10 is the default cost and your benchmarks is nonsensical (0.3ns/op means code compiled away by the compiler).

Comment: @Volker how can I benchmark time taken to execute the function?

Comment: This is largely a matter of opinion and highly dependent upon what level of security is necessary for your particular application. Even [NIST](https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html) and [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Work_Factor), two of the top sources of security recommendations, remain intentionally vague on the subject of work factors.

Comment: @commonSenseCode by not throwing away the result of the hash but e.g. keep it in a global.

Comment: @Volker I've been digging into this, and it doesn't feel like that's the problem. Even printing the hash doesn't change the result. I've also checked the error result, and it's fine, too. Even changing this to `result, _ = HashPassword(string(b.N), 10)` generates the same timing. I'm wondering if it has to do with the calculation of N^work itself? (Though these times are really really short, so I'm not convinced that's it either.)

Comment: @RobNapier This is the problem. Anything below 0.5 ns smells like optimized away. And 0.04ns is a clear sign that nothing was executed at all. You could peek a the generated assembly.

Comment: @Volker Agreed, but…what's happening? I can't figure out the Benchmark misuse.

Comment: I wonder if HashPassword() is being optimized away altogether? Not sure why changing the constant value would trigger that though.

Comment: Just adding for clarity to future readers: If someone gets access to your DB and pass-hashes, he will for sure not use some normal script-lang or lib for brute-forcing it. He will use a cloud-service with immensely GPU-powered power and insane optimized hash-algorithms. So you can't compare timings here with that. The goal here should not be to find a certain good hashround-number. Instead you should look how many rounds you can implement in YOUR system on YOUR hardware at maximum without reducing usability. Hashing is only one of many security-features :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not certain what's going on with Benchmark here. If you just time these, it works fine, and you can work out the right answer for you.

```
package main

import (
    "golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    cost := 10

    start := time.Now()
    bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte("password"), cost)
    end := time.Now()

    print(end.Sub(start) / time.Millisecond)
}
```

For a work factor of 10, on my MacBook Pro I get 78ms. A work factor of 11 is 154ms, and 12 is 334ms. So we're seeing roughly doubling, as expected.

The goal is not a work factor; it's a time. You want as long as you can live with. In my experience (mostly working on client apps), 80-100ms is a nice target because compared to a network request it's undetectable to the user, while being massive in terms of brute-force attacks (so the default of 10 is ideal for my common use).

I generally avoid running password stretching on servers if I can help it, but this scale can be a reasonable trade-off between server impact and security. Remember that attackers may use something dramatically faster than a MacBook Pro, and may use multiple machines in parallel; I pick 80-100ms because of user experience trade-offs. (I perform password stretching on the client when I can get away with it, and then apply a cheap hash like SHA-256 on the server.)

But if you don't do this very often, or can spend more time on it, then longer is of course better, and on my MacBook Pro a work factor of 14 is about 1.2s, which I would certainly accept for some purposes.

But there's a reason that 10 is still the default. It's not an unreasonable value.

Comment: so better to just use `DefaultCost` var from bcrypt package. Do you have an idea why the benchmarks don't work? when should one use benchmarks? I though it was a perfect use case for comparing bcrypt cost performances

Comment: I don't understand the Benchmark issue either. It's probably worth its own question. Probably worth exploring some other functions (to see if it's specific to the bcrypt function, or just something non-obvious about Benchmark generally).

Comment: Just a tip, you can use `time.Since(start)` instead of `time.Now().Sub(start)`

Comment: The benchmark issue is due to the fact that you aren't running the code `b.N` times.  This is [required and not optional](https://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/30/how-to-write-benchmarks-in-go) when writing Go benchmarks.

Comment: check my update the benchmark was incorrectly set, I used @Luke Josua Park resource and got it working. Do you think the output now makes sense it is roughly doubling with every increase of bcryp

Comment: Yes, you should expect doubling with each increase of the work factor. It's 2^n.

Comment: @RobNapier while time is the target on your side, it would be helpful to know how much cost would be at the very least a reasonable minimum for any given era as not everyone has top of the line machines and the question is always whether this old machine that  can only go so far with bcrypt but it would be still ugly because the machine is too old for example. basically a "how low can you go without impacting security too much"

Comment: Agreed. I generally scale work factors based on running tests on the slowest hardware I support, and target certain user experiences there (usually a "slightly annoying, but not too painful" user experience, with the assumption people upgrade eventually). This is also a reason to store your work factor in your data (which I think bcrypt does) so you can increase it over time while still being able to deal with old hashes. (This approach doesn't always work, especially when you're dealing with network protocols, but it's worth pursuing when possible.)